# How to make a div height adjusted between two divs with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to `bootstrap` and `css`, however with some code on internet, I was able to create my `welcome.jsp` page.

**What I wanted to do**
I wanted my main content div in between header and footer. Also I wanted the footer to be in fixed position.

**What I achieved**
I was able to create main div in between header and footer.

**problem**
when I reduce the zoom of my chrome browser, the main div height gets shrink, leaving unnecessary blank space between main div and footer.

**without any zoom**
[image]

**reduced zoom**
[image]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
#footer {
position:fixed;
height: 20px;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: green;
}
#main{
margin-top:-10px;
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #73AD21;
height: 550px;

}
</style>
<script src="../jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link  href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" >
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#header").load("header/header.jsp");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="header"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="main">CONTENT<br></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want that extra space between main div and footer. Is there any way that I can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with `height:100vh;` on `#main` element.

Answer (score 0):

just change fixed to relative:

```
<style>
#footer {
position:relative;
height: 20px;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix that you will need to get the height value from your screen dynamically.

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("content")[0];
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
var newValue=x-300;
console.log(x, newValue)
content.style.height=newValue+'px';
```

Sample:
[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/matoslucas/pen/WoqJwO)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the style for your `#main` div to

```
#mein {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```